# Generics appear not to be the same in class and method

Tags: c#, generics

I asked this question before but it was put on hold because the problem was a 'simple' conversion problem. For me this isn't. This is the first time I try to work with generics.

I have a `Class` like the code here without any errors:

```
internal class GridBox<T> : BoxBase // where T : new()
{
    public GridBox(Grid grid, GridBoxView view, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button)
        : base(grid, icon, caption, button)
    {
        View = view;
        DataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public GridBoxView View { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<T> DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

Next I use this `Class` to pass a lot of data between different `Classes` starting with the code below:

```
public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button) where T : IComparable<T>, new()
{
    Window window = Window.GetWindow(sender);
    Grid grid = Extensions.FindChild<Grid>(window);
    GridBoxView gridBox = new GridBoxView();

    return gridBox.Show<T>(new GridBox<T>(grid, gridBox, icon, caption, dataSource, button));
}
```

This code can be compiled without any errors. Am I right if I say that `where T : IComparable<T>` is needed to use `T` inside the `Method` and the extra `, new()` is needed to use it at `new GridBox<T>`? Again, first time experimenting with generics.

The above code that calls `Show<T>` is below here:

```
internal class GridBoxViewModel<T> : BoxBaseViewModel // where T : new()
{
    public T Show<T>(GridBox<T> gridBox)
    {
        // Set content item
        DataSource = gridBox.DataSource;

        // Set visual items and block the excecution code 
        AddView(gridBox.Grid, gridBox.View, gridBox.Icon, gridBox.Caption, gridBox.Button);

        // Return value
        return SelectedItem;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> DataSource { get; set; }
    public T SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Here the problems start. `DataSource = gridBox.DataSource` gives an error that it can't convert `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` which appears to me as the same. Both are referring to the same `Class Library` `[C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll]`.

The second problem is with `return SelectedItem;`. The error here is pretty much the same but a bit different tho. It can't convert `'T'` to `'T [Controls\ViewModels\GridBoxViewModel.cs(6)]'`.

The obvious reason for me is that the `T` at `internal class GridBoxViewModel<T> : BoxBaseViewModel` isn't the same `T` as at `public T Show<T>(GridBox<T> gridBox)`. Is this actually the cause and if so, how should I handle this problem and fix it?

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to infer that the `T` from `GridBoxViewModel` and the `T` from `GridBox` are the same type or have an implicit conversion between them?

Comment: `where T: new()` means only types with parameterless constructors are valid type arguments (which allows you to call `new T();` in the class/method), and `where T: IComparable<T>` means only types that implement the `IComparable<T>` interface can be used as type arguments (which allows you to call `CompareTo` on T within the class/method).  You don't appear to be using either of those in the code you show, so I'm not sure you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the generic parameter from `Show`:

```
public T Show(GridBox<T> gridBox)
```

the `T` type parameter is different to the one declared on the class which is why you get the compiler error.

Comment: Heh, pretty obvious I guess. This actually fixed it, tnx. Now I can start testing my code if it actually works.